# TabLayout with ViewPager refresh on Navigate Back

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-adapter, android-tablayout

I have tabs on the first screen and on the second screen, I have input fields that return to the first screen after submit. But when I return to the first screen, data is not updated in the recyclerview of the first tab. But when I go to the second tab and then return to first tab the data is rerendered. I want to rerender the first tab when I navigate back from the second screen. My TabLayout with ViewPager is in Fragment and I also check that my code which is inside onViewCreated runs when Screen opens first time and even after it navigate back from second screen but it makes no effect on recyclerview inside first tab.

TabLayout in onViewCreated:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {  
       
        tabLayout = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabLayout)  
        viewPager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewPager)  
  
        tabLayout!!.addTab(tabLayout!!.newTab().setText("Home"))  
        tabLayout!!.addTab(tabLayout!!.newTab().setText("Sport"))  
        tabLayout!!.addTab(tabLayout!!.newTab().setText("Movie"))  
        tabLayout!!.tabGravity = TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL  
  
        val adapter = MyAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager, tabLayout!!.tabCount)  
        viewPager!!.adapter = adapter  
  
        viewPager!!.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout))  
  
        tabLayout!!.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {  
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {  
                viewPager!!.currentItem = tab.position  
            }  
            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {  
  
            }  
            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {  
  
            }  
        })  
  
    }
```

My Adapter to for ViewPager:

```
class MyAdapter(private val myContext: Context, fm: FragmentManager, internal var totalTabs: Int) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {  
  
    // this is for fragment tabs  
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {  
        when (position) {  
            0 -> {  
              //  val homeFragment: HomeFragment = HomeFragment()  
                return HomeFragment()  
            }  
            1 -> {  
                return SportFragment()  
            }  
            2 -> {  
               // val movieFragment = MovieFragment()  
                return MovieFragment()  
            }  
            else -> return null  
        }  
    }  
  
    // this counts total number of tabs  
    override fun getCount(): Int {  
        return totalTabs  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to notify data changes in your `RecyclerView` like the API offers: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Yes its already added but issue is that once it gets back it run onViewCreated of main fragment but not the fragment used in tabs

Comment: Try a public interface. Search Stack Overflow for how to implement an interface!

Comment: I think its better if you share the solution